# vba excel vlookup: lookup value in stored array, lookup table in excel, output value to array

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am using vlookup to populate an array in vba.

The array (InfArray) is an ~100 row by 3 column array.  The first column of the array is already populated with integer values.  These integer values correspond to a name.  In one of my excel sheets I have a table that has each integer id listed with its corresponding name.  So I want to use the vlookup function to check the id integer and populate the second column of the array with the actual name.

Here is the code statement I have to assign the second column (original bad code):

```
For y = 1 To UBound(InfArray,1)
    Set InfArray(y,2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(InfArray(y,1), NameSheet.Range("B2:C244"), 2, False).Value
Next y
```

It is giving me a Object variable or With block variable not set error.

When I cursor over the code text after running, I see that the

```
NameSheet.Range("B2:C244")
```

is where the object variable or with block variable not set error is located.  This is really confusing.  I put a

```
Debug.Print NameSheet.Name
```

In the code prior to the error and it is giving me the correct name of the excel sheet in question.  So the code must be looking in the right worksheet, but somehow it is not getting the range...?

I'm lost, please help

EDIT: The error was a typo in the code

```
NameSheet.Range("B2:C244")
```

should have been

```
NamesSheet.Range("B2:C244")
```

Note the 's' at the end of NameS

It now works with the edits suggested

Working code line:

```
For y = 1 To UBound(InfArray,1)
    InfArray(y,2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(InfArray(y,1), NamesSheet.Range("B2:C244"), 2, False)
Next y
```

Apologies for the stoopid error.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the Set statement. It should only be used with object variables.

But also...

Piercing the boundary between VBA and Excel 100 times in a loop is not an efficient design. It would be much better to grab your table once, place it in a VBA array, and then just spin through this additional array to find the lookup values.

Comment: 'set' statement gone, still same error.  If I can't find an answer to why the vlookup won't work then I guess I will default to your second solution of just putting the lookup table in a vba array, however, I'm still curious why this keeps returning the object variable not set error

Comment: Can you post the current code (since you have made changes) that is not working? I'll see if I can workout the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.Value` from the [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65). The [Range.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) is not part of VLOOKUP.

```
For y = 1 To UBound(InfArray,1)
    InfArray(y,2) = Application.VLookup(InfArray(y,1), NameSheet.Range("B2:C244"), 2, False)
Next y
```

I've also reduced to down to `Application.VLookup` which is all that is necessary.

Comment: I removed the '.value' and trimmed off the 'Excel' from before 'Application.VLookup', still getting the same problem

Comment: @agnuke  -My apologies. You also do not need to `Set` the value returned by VLOOKUP, merely assign it with =.